# How to select rows in a DataFrame based on rows in another DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have two dataframes, df1 looks like as follows:

```
id  year    CalendarWeek    DayName interval    counts
1   2014    1   sun 10:30   3
1   2014    1   sun 11:30   4
1   2014    2   wed 12:00   5
1   2014    2   fri 9:00    2
2   2014    1   sun 13:00   3
2   2014    1   sun 14:30   1
2   2014    1   mon 10:30   2
2   2014    2   wed 14:00   3
2   2014    2   fri 15:00   5
3   2014    1   thu 16:30   2
3   2014    1   thu 17:00   1
3   2014    2   sat 12:00   2
3   2014    2   sat 13:30   3
```

And df2 looks like as follows:

```
id  year    CalendarWeek    DayName interval    NewCounts
1   2014    1   sun 10:00   2
1   2014    1   sun 10:30   4
1   2014    1   sun 11:30   5
1   2014    2   wed 10:30   6
1   2014    2   wed 12:00   3
1   2014    2   fri 8:30    1
1   2014    2   fri 9:00    2
2   2014    1   sun 12:30   3
2   2014    1   sun 13:00   4
2   2014    1   sun 14:30   4
2   2014    1   mon 9:00    35
2   2014    1   mon 10:30   1
2   2014    2   wed 12:30   23
2   2014    2   wed 14:00   4
2   2014    2   fri 15:00   3
3   2014    1   thu 14:30   1
3   2014    1   thu 15:00   3
3   2014    1   thu 16:30   34
3   2014    1   thu 17:00   5
3   2014    2   sat 12:00   3
3   2014    2   sat 13:30   4
3   2014    2   sat 14:00   2
```

I want to pick up all rows in df2 that match the columns id,year,CalendarWeek,DayName and interval in df1.
The result I want should looks like as follows:

```
id  year    CalendarWeek    DayName interval    NewCounts
1   2014    1   sun 10:30   4
1   2014    1   sun 11:30   5
1   2014    2   wed 12:00   3
1   2014    2   fri 9:00    2
2   2014    1   sun 13:00   4
2   2014    1   sun 14:30   4
2   2014    1   mon 10:30   1
2   2014    2   wed 14:00   4
2   2014    2   fri 15:00   3
3   2014    1   thu 16:30   34
3   2014    1   thu 17:00   5
3   2014    2   sat 12:00   3
3   2014    2   sat 13:30   4
```

In Python, how to select these specific rows in a dataframe based on columns in another dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) and pass the list of columns to param `on`, the default type of merge is [`'inner'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) which only matches where values exist in both dfs:

```
In [2]:

df.merge(df1, on=['id','year','CalendarWeek','DayName','interval'])
Out[2]:
    id  year  CalendarWeek DayName interval  counts  NewCounts
0    1  2014             1     sun    10:30       3          4
1    1  2014             1     sun    11:30       4          5
2    1  2014             2     wed    12:00       5          3
3    1  2014             2     fri     9:00       2          2
4    2  2014             1     sun    13:00       3          4
5    2  2014             1     sun    14:30       1          4
6    2  2014             1     mon    10:30       2          1
7    2  2014             2     wed    14:00       3          4
8    2  2014             2     fri    15:00       5          3
9    3  2014             1     thu    16:30       2         34
10   3  2014             1     thu    17:00       1          5
11   3  2014             2     sat    12:00       2          3
12   3  2014             2     sat    13:30       3          4
```

If your 'id' column is your index, you'd have to reset the index on both df's so that they become a column in the df's, this is because the inner join will produce an incorrect result if you specify the `on` list of columns and also specify `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`:

```
In [4]:

df.merge(df1, on=['year','CalendarWeek','DayName','interval'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[4]:
    year  CalendarWeek DayName interval  counts  NewCounts
id                                                        
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          2
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          4
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          5
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          6
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          3
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          1
1   2014             1     sun    10:30       3          2
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          2
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          4
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          5
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          6
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          3
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          1
1   2014             1     sun    11:30       4          2
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          2
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          4
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          5
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          6
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          3
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          1
1   2014             2     wed    12:00       5          2
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          2
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          4
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          5
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          6
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          3
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          1
1   2014             2     fri     9:00       2          2
2   2014             1     sun    13:00       3          3
2   2014             1     sun    13:00       3          4
..   ...           ...     ...      ...     ...        ...
2   2014             2     fri    15:00       5          4
2   2014             2     fri    15:00       5          3
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          1
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          3
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2         34
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          5
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          3
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          4
3   2014             1     thu    16:30       2          2
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          1
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          3
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1         34
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          5
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          3
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          4
3   2014             1     thu    17:00       1          2
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          1
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          3
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2         34
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          5
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          3
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          4
3   2014             2     sat    12:00       2          2
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          1
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          3
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3         34
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          5
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          3
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          4
3   2014             2     sat    13:30       3          2

[96 rows x 6 columns]
```

so to reset the index just do `df = df.reset_index(0)` and likewise for the other df, after merging you can then set the index back to id so:

```
merged = df.merge(df1, on=['id','year','CalendarWeek','DayName','interval'])
merged = merged.reset_index()
```